# Displaying information from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to display the names from my 2d array.

```
public class last{

static void afficherMINU(String[][]nomPre){
    for(int i=0;i<nomPre.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<nomPre.length;j++){
            System.out.printf(nomPre[i][j]+"\n");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String []args){
    String[]codePerm={"VILC15539307","NDIJ19129406","LANM29089409","JEAJ03108909","TOUS17529409","TRED01039200","AUCM28579305"};
    String[][]nomPre={{"VILLENEUVE-ASSE","CINDY"},{"NDIAYE YEND","JEAN-LOUIS RUDY"},{"LANDRY-VIGNEAULT GARCIA","MARCEL"},{"JEAN-BAPTISTE","JOSEPH-RAYMOND MARC"},{"TOUCHETTE","SOPHIE ANNE-MARIE"},
    {"TREMBLAY","DENIS MARC-ANDRE PIERRE"},{"AUCLAIR-JULIEN","MARIE-ISABELLE"}};

    afficherMINU(nomPre);

    }
}
```

The first information from `"String[][]nomPre"` in the double array is the last name followed by their name. For example when i display the array it should look like

```
VILLENEUVE-ASSE, CINDY
NDIAYE YEND, JEAN-LOUIS RUDY
```

and so on. But my code keeps printing:

```
VILLENEUVE-ASSE
CINDY
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at last.afficherMINU(last.java:6)
    at last.main(last.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop has the wrong termination bound. The value of `nomPre.length` is 7 (if I counted correctly), but the inner loop needs to stop after the length of `nomPre[i]`, since that's what's indexed by `j`. Use this instead:

```
for(int j=0;j<nomPre[i].length;j++){ // NOT nomPre.length
    System.out.printf(nomPre[i][j]+"\n");
}
```

Better yet, capture the `i`<sup>th</sup> row in the outer loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<nomPre.length;i++){
    String[] row = nomPre[i];
    for(int j=0;j<row.length;j++){
        System.out.printf(row[j]+"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It prints perfectly now. But to have the first element from my 2d array to print so that i can have the last name and the first name on the same line i would have to mess arround with the [i] and [j]?

Comment: @user3268216 - You can use `print()` instead of `println()` and then add a `println()` inside the outer loop after the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `afficherMINU`, this

```
for(int j=0;j<nomPre.length;j++) {
```

should be

```
for(int j=0;j<nomPre[i].length;j++) {
```

Or use, [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(nomPre));
```

Or use a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop,

```
for(String[] arr : nomPre){
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```